# Fischer Yates shuffle in coffee-script

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, shuffle

Assuming that `Math.random()` produces evenly distributed random numbers between 0 and 1, is this a correct implementation of the Fischer Yates shuffle? I am looking for a very random, even distribution, where the number of shuffled elements in an input array (`arr`) can be specified (as `required`).

```
shuffle = (arr, required)->
  rnd = (int) ->
    r = Math.random() * int
    Math.round r

  len = arr.length-1

  for i in [len..1]
    random = rnd(i)
    temp = arr[random]
    arr[random] = arr[i]
    arr[i] = temp
    break if i < len - (required - 2)

  return arr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things:

- Rather than `Math.round()`, try `Math.floor()`; in your
  implementation `Math.round()` gives the first element (at index 0)
  and the last element less of a chance than all the other elements
  (.5/len vs. 1/len). Note that on the first iteration, you input `arr.length - 1` for `arr.length` elements.
- If you're going to have a `required`
  variable, you might as well make it optional, in that it defaults to the length of the array: `shuffle = (arr,
  required=arr.length)`
- You return the entire array even though you only shuffled the last elements. Consider instead returning `arr[arr.length - required ..]`
- What if `required` isn't in the range `[0,arr.length]`?

Putting it all together (and adding some flair):

```
    shuffle = (arr, required=arr.length) ->
      randInt = (n) -> Math.floor n * Math.random()
      required = arr.length if required > arr.length
      return arr[randInt(arr.length)] if required <= 1

      for i in [arr.length - 1 .. arr.length - required]
        index = randInt(i+1)
        # Exchange the last unshuffled element with the 
        # selected element; reduces algorithm to O(n) time
        [arr[index], arr[i]] = [arr[i], arr[index]]

      # returns only the slice that we shuffled
      arr[arr.length - required ..]

    # Let's test how evenly distributed it really is
    counter = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
    permutations = ["1,2,3","1,3,2","2,1,3","2,3,1","3,2,1","3,1,2"]
    for i in [1..12000]
      x = shuffle([1,2,3])
      counter[permutations.indexOf("#{x}")] += 1

    alert counter
```

Comment: That is all good, thanks. Except that the number 8 never appears last. It is very important to me that the distribution is correct.

Comment: Very true; I should've taken my own advice; silly pigeon-hole principle. Okay, so if you make it `randInt(i+1)` it should work.

Comment: Looks ok to me now. Are you sure? do you know how I could test/check it?

Comment: Well, if you're willing to write a test script, you can put in an array like [1,2,3,4], run it 10000 times, and frequency bin each of the permutations to see if they're equally likely.

Comment: Now I'm reasonably sure: 1713,1620,1676,1681,1688,1622

Comment: Great. I just did the same test, getting similar results. It is actually surprising how close the numbers are.