# I need help optimising a function

Tags: javascript, loops, angle

Basically I want to generate a an angle (0 - 360 degrees) that isn't within a specified range of a number of other angles. I already made this function to check two angles:

```
function check(angle1, angle2, range) {
    var diff = angle1 - angle2;

    if(Math.abs(diff % 360) <= range || (360-Math.abs(diff % 360)) <= range) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Simple enough, but I need to check a random angle against all other angles, proceed if it passes, generate a new angle and recheck if it fails, and recognise when it's not possible for any new angle to pass.

I think this would work:

```
var others = [array of objects];

...

for(var i = 0; i < 360; i++) {
    var pass = true;
    for(var n = 0; n < others.length; n++) {
        if(check(i, others[n].angle, 5)) {
            pass = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(pass) return i;
}

return false;
```

However that is a *lot* of looping and I would much prefer a random angle rather than  incrementing. Is there a faster and better way to do this? Thanks.

Edit: decided to do something like this, got the idea from @TheBronx's answer.

```
var angles = [];

var range = 5;

function alterAngle(a, n) {
  var angle = a + n;
  if(angle < 0) angle = 360 + angle;
  if(angle > 360) angle = angle - 360;
  return angle;
}



// in the function

var angle = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);

if(angles.indexOf(angle) == -1) {
  for(var i = -range; i <= range; i++)
    angles.push(alterAngle(angle, i));
}
```

Comment: Perhaps [codereview.se] might be a more suitable site for this question?

Comment: Just curious, the range is a small value? like 5º? How many angles can you have in the worst case?

Comment: Are your angles whole numbers?

Comment: Probably about 30 angles max, and yes the angles are whole numbers.

Comment: Answer please on @TheBronx question about range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea. Imagine your angles are cards in a deck. Once you generate a random angle, you remove that angle from the deck, and also the angles within your range.
When you have to generate a new angle, instead of generating a random between 0..360 you just have to "pick a card". This will always work, unless you don't have more "cards" available.

The problem is, do you have a lot of cards? Do you have enough time to initialize the "cards" at start?

Just an idea... Don't know if it is good or not but seems promising.

Comment: That's a great idea! I'll just test it out, I'll post it if it works. Thanks.

Comment: Managing the ranges is proving to be quite difficult. I thought I could just splice a chunk from the array but then you end up splicing jumps where you've previously spliced. It might work still if I figure this out.

Comment: yep, removing is a problem. Once you select an angle you have to check and remove up to `range*2` angles. But checking is not very time consuming, and you can remove all angles at once (when you know where to start and finish the splice)... it may work.

Comment: I ended up basically doing the opposite to what you said, adding the whole range to an array and checking if the generated angle is in that array. You gave me the idea though, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This one

```
if(Math.abs(diff % 360) <= range || (360-Math.abs(diff % 360)) <= range) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
}
```

you could make in this way, this will reduce operations

```
return Math.abs(diff % 360) <= range || (360-Math.abs(diff % 360)) <= range;
```

Comment: and if you store `Math.abs(diff % 360)` in a var you don't have to calculate it twice. Its probably not the solution he wants, but as he uses `function check` a lot of times optimizing it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Based on a previous question of mine: [Fischer Yates shuffle in coffee-script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12929058/665261)

```
var counter, i, permutations, shuffle, x, _i;

// Fischer Yates shuffle algorithm
shuffle = function(arr, required) {
  var i, index, randInt, _i, _ref, _ref1, _ref2;
  if (required == null) {
    required = arr.length;
  }
  randInt = function(n) {
    return Math.floor(n * Math.random());
  };
  if (required > arr.length) {
    required = arr.length;
  }
  if (required <= 1) {
    return arr[randInt(arr.length)];
  }
  for (i = _i = _ref = arr.length - 1, _ref1 = arr.length - required; _ref <= _ref1 ? _i <= _ref1 : _i >= _ref1; i = _ref <= _ref1 ? ++_i : --_i) {
    index = randInt(i + 1);
    _ref2 = [arr[i], arr[index]], arr[index] = _ref2[0], arr[i] = _ref2[1];
  }
  return arr.slice(arr.length - required);
};


// generate array of all possible angles
var angles = []
for(i=0;i<360;i++){ angles.push(i) }

// shuffle as many as you need (20 in this example)
var shuffled = shuffle(angles,20)

// check the result
console.log(shuffled)

// simply deal off values from this shuffled array as needed
```